# CastError: Cast to Array failed for value

Tags: node.js, mongoose

When I receive the data from post and try to parser it there is an error.

This is the details about the question:

I have two models:

```
var tags = require('../tag/tag.model'),
  mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var OpportunitiesSchema = new Schema({
    employeeTitle: String,
    tagline: Boolean,
    description:String,
    location:String,
    isPreferred:Boolean,
    tags: [
      {
        type:Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Tag'
      }
    ]
});

module.exports.opportunities = mongoose.model('Opportunities', OpportunitiesSchema);
```

And  I have another model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TagSchema = new Schema({
  id: Number,
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Tag', TagSchema);
```

My function like this:

```
var Opportunities = require('./opportunities.model').opportunities;
exports.create = function(req, res) {
  //addOpportunitites.save(req.body, function(err, tag) {
  //    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  //    return res.json(201, tag);
  //});

  var newOpportunity = new Opportunities(req.body);

  newOpportunity.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      return res.json(201);
    }

  })
};
```

When I sent a data like this:

```
{
  "employeeTitle": "Digital Agency Employee, downtown Chicago",
  "tagline": "My company is offering $1000 referral bonus and I'll give you half!",
  "description": "<p>Looking for someone who has the following abilities: <ul><li></li></ul></p>",
  "location": "",
  "tags": [
    545454,45467
  ]
}
```

There is an error:

```
{
    [ValidationError: Opportunities validation failed]
    message: 'Opportunities validation failed',
    name: 'ValidationError',
    errors: {
        tags: {
            [CastError: Cast to Array failed for value "545454,45467" at path "tags"]
            message: 'Cast to Array failed for value "545454,45467" at path "tags"',
            name: 'CastError',
            kind: 'Array',
            value: [Object],
            path: 'tags',
            reason: undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `tags`, you're sending `Numbers`, presumably the `id` in the tag model, but in the `Opportunities` model, you're storing `ObjectId`s, which is the `_id` generated by mongo.

Comment: It depends what the rest of your code looks like and wha kind of data you want to pass back and forth to the frontend. If you change the POST data's `tags` to the ObjectID as a string (ex. `"561fa3aac09d1fa4eb63f806"`), I would expect it to work as is. Alternatively, you could look them up in the controller on the backend, using your current `id` field.